# execute commands in jenkinsfile as specific user

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running jenkinsfile and would like to run it as specific user (the tool can't be executed by privileged user) but running `su jenkins` doesn't change anything, any other ideas ?

```
15:48:35  + whoami
15:48:35  + echo root
15:48:35  root
[Pipeline] sh
15:48:36  + su **** #(jenkins)
[Pipeline] sh
15:48:36  + whoami
15:48:36  + echo root
15:48:36  root
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: Consider to use [credentials](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc), please.

Comment: Did you run su and whoami in one sh script? Please share your pipeline script

Comment: I had to put in Dockerfile 'USER jenkins' at the end as the solution